# Is there a way I can find the average of my results I made in this query? Newer to sql

Tags: sql

[really just stuck on figuring out how to also create an average row or another query to find the averages of the Count_Totals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlfyk.png)

tried joins, select statement in the select statement, some other things similar but idk what I am doing

Comment: Please always put your query into the question as text, but yes, there's an `AVG` aggregate function in SQL.

Comment: Looking into unions. You may find grouping sets to be useful also.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT AVG(Count_total)

FROM

(
*Your original query posted on the question as image*
)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which database you use; answer might depend on that.

---

I don't have your table so I'll illustrate it using the one that contains information about employees; one of the columns is `job`.

This is what you currently have:

```
SQL> select job,
  2         count(*) as count_total
  3  from emp
  4  group by job;

JOB       COUNT_TOTAL
--------- -----------
CLERK               4
SALESMAN            4
PRESIDENT           1
MANAGER             3
ANALYST             2
```

If you're interested in average calculated as

```
(4 + 4 + 1 + 3 + 2) / 5 = 14 / 5 = 2.8
```

Then (as already suggested) use current query as a source (either as a subquery or a CTE) for the one that utilizes the `avg` (*average*) function:

```
SQL> select avg(count_total) as avg_total
  2  from (select job,
  3               count(*) as count_total
  4        from emp
  5        group by job
  6       );

 AVG_TOTAL
----------
       2,8
```

On the other hand, you can fetch that result alongside current values your initial query returned by using average function in its analytic form (if your database supports it):

```
SQL> select job,
  2         count(*) as count_total,
  3         avg(count(*)) over () avg_total
  4  from emp
  5  group by job;

JOB       COUNT_TOTAL  AVG_TOTAL
--------- ----------- ----------
CLERK               4        2,8
SALESMAN            4        2,8
PRESIDENT           1        2,8
MANAGER             3        2,8
ANALYST             2        2,8

SQL>
```